# New create-react-app install with newly installed antd results in sections with black on black set by default theme

Tags: antd

Used create-react-app successfully.

Did `yarn add antd` successfully.

Copied the second layout example from https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-basic to `App.js`.

Here's the end result: [image]

I expect this is incorrect.

Did I miss a step or something? I've used antd before without such problems.

Comment: Did you copy the example with its corresponding CSS styles? It might be a side effect from your local CSS.
Also, what container are you using to wrap the Layout component? It might have layout restrictions that force the UI to wrap and twist. 
A code example of what you are doing would help to troubleshoot the root cause.

Comment: I think its normal. If you open the demo on antd documentation and remove the styling on index.css you will get the same output.